# How do I convert fluorescent cans to LED?

Tags: lighting

I have these very strange 6 inch recessed lighting "cans" in my kitchen, that it hate. I pulled them apart thinking a could simply wire a new fixture, but I'm stymied.  I purchased a Halo LED retrofit, but it seems to assume I have a standard bulb socket.  Also, even if I just wired it to my existing can, I have two black wires and two white wires in each can.  The new fixture only has one of each.  What can I do here?  I would sure appreciate some advice.

Thanks,
Laura

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a make and model number on the light bulb socket?  How about on the fixture?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the electrical connection you are seeing is from the ballast ( the thing that Makes the fluorescent tube light) that is wired into the other metal box part of the Can. You would need to remove that ballast to put in another type of light in. It would be in the little panel that opens up that I can see in the 2nd Picture. In that box there should be the main electrical wire that is feeding the ballast then the ballast has 4 wires coming out. You would want to remove it and then have a White and Black go back though that flex.   Though your stumbling block there might be how to mount the new LED Trim to the Existing housing.

Do you have room in the attic to see the Cans? It might be easier to replace the can from the Attic with a new Can (they are less then $10)

Comment: I agree on replacement if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  That is what I suspected.  Unfortunately there is no access above the lights. The lights are housed in a dropped area and out bedroom (with 200 yr old hardwood floors) is located above.  If I had an electrician come out, do you think they could replace them as you described above?  Or are they going to tell me that they'd have to open up the whole ceiling?

Comment: Its hard to say.   If you can find a LED trim that you like and you can attach it to the existing housing, then sure. You can do as I mentioned and remove the ballast and rewire the LED trim into the existing.   Did you open up the little metal box? There is a tab at the top that releases the little door. Take a picture of what is inside.

Comment: Maybe something like [this fixture](http://www.designingwithlight.com/MKACatpdfs/1101IE.PDF)

Answer (score 0):

Those fixtures cannot be converted or changed. They are proprietary CFL fixtures in every way; sockets, wiring, ballast. 
Lightolier brand BTW.

Your only option is to replace the entire fixture.

Comment: That's right.  They are Lightolier but I couldn't find a model number.